# LaTeX formula in gnuplot

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I need to write LaTeX expression in the key, something like V_x with no italics in epslatex terminal.

I have tried `$\text{V}_{\text{x}}$` but it does not give the desired output. Is there anyway to have equations using gnuplot? Below is my full script

```
set terminal epslatex color standalone  size 5.0in,5.25in
set output 'output.tex'
pl 'file.txt' u ($2-1):(($1-21.5) w p pt 5 ps 1.0 lc 7 title '\text{V}_{\text{x}}=0.6' 
unset out
set out
system('latex output.tex && dvips output.dvi && ps2pdf output.ps')
system('mv output.ps out2.eps')
unset terminal
set out
```

Comment: That should work with `epslatex`. What is it, that doesn't work? Note, that you must compile gnuplot's output file manually to get the final result.

Comment: @Christoph I have included my whole script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) insert missing close parenthesis 2) add $...$ around TeX math fragment 3) if you are not using the amsmath package, change \text to \textrm:

```
pl 'file.txt' u ($2-1):(($1-21.5)) w p pt 5 ps 1.0 lc 7 title '$\text{V}_{\text{x}}=0.6$',\
   'file.txt' w p pt 6 title '$\textrm{V}_{\textrm{x}}=0.6$'
```

[image]

Comment: What if, instead of 0.6, I want to use a variable (of Gnuplot)?

Comment: To print variable FOO: `plot ... tittle sprintf("$\text{V}_{\text{x}}=%.2f$", FOO)`